# Single quote in SQL

Tags: android, sqlite

I get this error message:

```
03-30 00:51:50.373 30267-30267/com.example.text E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
03-30 00:51:54.273 30267-30267/com.example.text E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "hand": syntax error
03-30 00:51:54.273 30267-30267/com.example.text E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.example.text, PID: 30267
                                                                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "hand": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Result (Date, Name, Content) VALUES ('20170330_005134', 'Next, adjust the collar.', 'Next, adjust the collar.

                                                                  First, put your left'hand into miyatsukuchi

                                                                  and adjust the collar on the right side

                                                                  so It lies ﬂat. Then, adjust the left collar

                                                                  so it lies ﬂat. There should be a ﬁst-sized space between

                                                                  the back of your neck and the collar.');
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1798)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1729)
                                                                      at seeto.fyp.textcamera.ResultHelper.addResult(ResultHelper.java:101)
                                                                      at seeto.fyp.textcamera.ResultActivity$2.onClick(ResultActivity.java:74)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

I know the problem occurs on the single quote in the text, while I need the single quote (or double quote) in some case.

I have tried `content = content.replace("'", "\'");`, but it seems doesn't work.

How can I insert the data to the database with the single and double quote?

```
public void addResult(String name, String date, String content) {
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + tbName + " (" + keyDate + ", " + keyName + ", " + keyContent + ") VALUES ('" + date + "', '" + name + "', '" + content + "');");
}
```

Comment: "Single quote in SQL" = you are missing a quote in your SQL query. If your text contains a quote, I don't know how you would handle it

Comment: You should use parameterized queries, don't concatenate strings.

Comment: by calling `database.insert()` ?

Comment: Like @Scovetta said, use a parameterized query.  That way you don't have these problems, you're safe from SQL injection, and you get performance improvements.  Using concatenation for values in SQL queries is absolutely unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, single quotes must be escaped by doubling them.
There would be a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)) to do this, but it is easier to just use parameters:

```java
public void addResult(String name, String date, String content) {
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + tbName +
                     " (" + keyDate + ", " + keyName + ", " + keyContent + ")" +
                     " VALUES (?, ?, ?);",
                     new Object[]{ date, name, content });
}
```

Even easier is to use [insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)), which creates the SQL command for you:

```java
public void addResult(String name, String date, String content) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(keyDate, date);
    cv.put(keyName, name);
    cv.put(keyContent, content);
    database.insertOrThrow(tbName, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Typically, you can escape single quotes by doubling them up and double quotes by inserting a backslash.

So, using your example:

```
content = content.replace("'", "''")
content = content.replace("\"", "\\\"")
```

Comment: SQL does not use backslash escaping.